# Django logged errors not sent by mail

Tags: django, email, logging

In my django website, I log errors using the logging module:

```
logger.error('Error')
```

I want these errors to be sent by mail.

However, no mails are being sent.

I use this configuration to see the mail send in the console (and when I get error 500, I see the mail in the console):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

I have tried this logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = { 
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        }   
    },  
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        },  
    }   
}
```

but I do no see the mails in the console when the error is logged. I only see the error message.

What can I do to be able to send the logged errors by mail?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set up [ADMINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins) setting?

Comment: ADMINS has to be set in your settings/configuration file like `(('John', 'john@example.com'), ('Mary', 'mary@example.com'))`, more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins

Comment: ADMINS setting is already set; I said I see the mail in the console when there is an error 500 (because EMAIL_BACKEND is set to console).